# Bluetooth switch does nothing

Tags: bluetooth

When I oped the bluetooth page of the settings, the bluetooth switch is off and the page states "Turn on to connect devices". When I turn the switch to on, simply nothing on the page changes, yet the switch stays on.

Due to this it is impossible to look for or connect devices.

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 with a 5.13.0 kernel.

Comment: Have you tried killall gnome-control-center

Comment: please edit the post to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Are you using 20.10? as that used the 5.8 kernel*

Answer (score -1):

Do you have **Blueman** installed?
If so, please execute

```
blueman-adapters
```

as it turn on the bluetooth adapter and check its configs.